# How to insert current time and date in neo4j node

Tags: php, neo4j

I am trying to insert Current time and date in node (from a php page) so that I will be able to check that which user signup to my website at what time and date.
Like by using 'now()' in mysqli we insert '2017-04-16 16:23:35'.

Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Cypher to insert this, just set the property to the `timestamp()` function, which captures the current instant in milliseconds that you can format to a date string when needed.

EDIT:

As Michael Hunger mentioned, [APOC Procedures](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/) has [several date/time formatting, parsing, and conversion functions](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_date_time_support) that can help you here.

Comment: I have already used Timestamp() function. And it insert the data '1492339384532' but when i am trying to convert in into readable data it  like _echo date('m/d/Y h:i:s ',1492339384532)_ Shows me 05/08/49260 01:55:32 Which is wrong. Answer should be 04/16/2017 16:xx:xx smthing like this.

Comment: there is a library called apoc, that has a function `apoc.date.format(timestamp())` https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/